# Access dual booted OS from VirtualBox

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, boot, virtualbox

I have a LinuxKali/OSX dual boot. I have to install some packages in the linux system but as the Wifi drivers do not work without those packages (Mac air has NO ethernet) I would like to access the linux boot from virtual box in my OSX to access the OSX wifi drivers.

Is that even possible? The linux system is set up completely with its own EFI boot so I would just need to boot this EFI partition through VirtualBox?

EDIT: Partition setup (1 harddisk)

```
sda1    MAC-EFI
sda2    macintoshHD
sda3    recoveryMac
sda4    LinuxEFI
sda5    linux root(encrypted)
```

Comment: Seeing how there’s probably only a single EFI system partition, it’s rather unlikely this would even boot.

Comment: ? you think the dual boot is not booting at all? I assure you when I select the boot partition which I constructed in the options menu of my mac I enter grub 2.0 and from there I can(and did) boot into linux. That made me think I could just boot this partition in virtual box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea of what you are trying to do is wrong: even if you manage to get a hold of the wifi drivers, why should BSD drivers work on Linux? Also, newer Macs have 802.11ac-compliant wifi cards, for which there is very little support outside the proprietary world. You may very well find out that there is no Linux driver yet for the particular card in your pc. It may turn out that your only option is to buy a wifi dongle.

At any rate: I do not know how to boot your Kali install from VirtualBox running on MacOS, I know that I don't need it. All you need to do is to install `hfsprogs`, which you can download (from [this Web page](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=hfsprogs)) from the MAC and put onto a USB key formatted via NTFS (common to both MacOS and Linux), then boot Kali and mount the Mac disk via the command:

```
  mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sda1 /mnt/macosx
```

This will mount the Mac partition (I assumed it is /dev/sda1, change accordingly if your differs) onto the /mnt/macosx mountpoint which you must have previously created.

Comment: Broadcom has a linux driver for my card:[http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php], but to install it I have to install many linux-header packages with many dependencies. It would be a lot easier if the linux partition can connect to the web and download any dependencies on its own.

Comment: @user3683367 Yes, good luck with that. Broadcomm drivers are notoriously hooribly buggy.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `hfsprogs` will only mount the filesystem? This will not allow me a direct connection to the web via the Wifi hardware or? So you would suggest to just buy a dongle? I do not really want to spend another couple of days on getting wifi to work..

Comment: @user3683367 Yes, you are right: hfsprogs will only mount the file system, nothing more. As for the dongle, just check Google to see which dongle works out of the box with kali.